# Should the android application create SDP by it's own?

Tags: android, webrtc, sdp

I am writing an WebRTC client for Android.
I am having my own signalling server.

I have a web API which accepts SDP to create session on web server!

What I want to know is that: How would I create SDP from the Android app which will be used to pass it to the web API?

Is there any 3rd party library which can be used to generate SDP from Android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Android native for webRTC, in that case your Android app will be the offerer. Invoke createOffer to generate the offer SDP in Android end. Its similar process how you start offer from any web based WebRTC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You should receive the SDP directly from the other peer and from your WebRTC stack for the local endpoint. You should not touch this SDP just pass it as is. You need to parse the SDP from signalling message.

Otherwise basic [SDP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566) is pretty simple (just a few lines in clear text), however with WebRTC it becomes very complicated because of the [ICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment) offers.

Comment: If you might have worked on the WebRTCApp demo application for Android which is available with the WebRTC SDK, in `WebSocketRTCClient#connectToRoomInternal`, the `RoomParametersFetcher` is requesting the `Signalling` Params from the server and SDP is used to create the offer for the peer and this is where I am confused.
<br>
In my case, my server is expecting a SDP from the application. So is the my question to generate SDP from the application!!